# Capybara Element returned by Find method is taking a wrong coordinate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I have running a System Test with Ruby On Rails and Minitest, but an error is shown.

**Error:**
RequestsTest#test_Admin_User_should_create_request:
Selenium: :WebDriver: :Error: :ElementClickInterceptedError:
element click intercepted: Element input-tag box#itemsClick">... is not clickable at point (686, 23).
Other element would receive the click: …
(Session info: chrome=120.0.6099.130)
test/system/requests_test.rb:480:in execute_test_new_request'
test/system/requests_test.rb:54:in block in class:RequestsTest'

**HTML:**

```
<a id="request__tags-list" href="#" class="input-tag-items" data-action="click->input-tag-box#itemsClick"></a>
```

**My Test:**

```
tags_list = find("#request__tags-list")
puts tags_list.rect
tags_list.click  # click on link
```

I tried using click_link method but it didn't work either.  The same error is shown.

I noticed that "tags_list.rect" prints coordinates that do not correspond to the tags_list coordinates.

```
#<struct Selenium::WebDriver::Rectangle x=316.6037902832031, y=31.733491897583008, width=739, height=20>
```

when in reality, the Y coordinate is much further down the page, 480 approximately.

Some idea what is happening.

Thanks!

**SO:** Windows 11

**Ruby Version:** ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [x64-mingw-ucrt]

**Rails Version:** Rails 7.0.8

**UPDATE:**

**Screenshoot:**
[image]

Comment: As the error states, you header would receive the click rather than the intended target. Can you do a `save_and_open_screenshot` and see what capybara is seeing? You have to figure out why your header is blocking in front of your link you are trying to click. It would help to see more code for how the header relates to the link, and also the generated html from the page.

Comment: What I'm seeing is that the tags_list element is placed under the Header element, which has the CSS property "display: fixed".  This is because the form does not fit on the screen, so it scrolls vertically.

Comment: You can change the size of the screen (even headless) in the selenium set code. Default size is 1400x1400 (horizontal x vertical). If it's large enough it shouldn't have to scroll.

Comment: You might also be able to use `taglist.element.location_once_scrolled_into_view`. You could store the location in a variable then click on that location. Or maybe just use the command to get it  to scroll into the view and do a `click()`.

Comment: I set default size at 1920x1080 and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Does the screenshot show it in view at that size? The second value should be the vertical if I recall correctly. So you went from 1400 vertical to 1028 vertical. It looks like you made it smaller vertically. You need to set it to something like 1400x2000.

Comment: Regardless of the resolution I configure, it always scrolls vertically, so the tags_list element is always positioned under the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had configure the laptop resolution screen at 125% when I bought it.  For some reason Chrome calculate wrong the elements coordinates.  This don't happen using Firefox.

The coordinates are shown correctly now:

```
#<struct Selenium::WebDriver::Rectangle x=315.7134704589844, y=347.7594451904297, width=738, height=20>
```

Beartech, thank you by your help.